# Does applying through recruitment consultants work?

Tags: job-search

I am currently job hunting, and generally get more interviews applying directly then through recruitment consultants. I am wondering if this is the norm? It is extremely frustrating, for example one agency right now who I have made an application with keeps on promising to tell me when I will hear back for an interview, but is never getting back to me unless I really chase them up.

Comment: VTC, because whether recruiters work or not is pretty much a matter of opinion..

Comment: It's important to remember that from the recruiter's point of view, *you're not the customer, you're the product.*  Getting *you* a job isn't a high priority for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recruitment agencies are usually an extra "gate" between you and the prospective employer. They need to give and keep up good impressions with their clients (clients being the companies who are using their services to recruit people).
Recruitment agences filter their resource pool (candidates) and shortlist candidates depending on the client's requests (including experience, educational qualifications among other factors).

Are the recruitment agencies posting salary brackets in their job adverts? If not, you might be communicating your salary expectations with the recruitment agency, and your expection does not match the client's salary brackets.

I have had mixed opinions about recruitment agencies and recruiters. Some help and do their utmost in keeping job seekers updated about their applications and even offer advise, and others just treat job seekers as a pool of candidates.

And always be honest and throughough with recruiters. If you give them a bad impression about yourself or reason to believe that you are not trustworthy, they are keeping your profile as a last resort... if they send you for an interview, you are not just presenting an image of yourself, but also presnting the recruiter, and if they send candidates which show negative traits, then they are perceived to be of poor "taste" in candidates and shortlisting.

I am not judging you in any way or assuming anything, but am trying to give you a clear picture of the situation when working with recruiters and recruitment agencies.

And be careful when working with recruitment agencies, if you are currently employed, take note of which recruitment agencies they work with (if any), and avoid them at all costs. They do not have any reason to spoil your plans with your current employer (after all your current employer will use their services if you leave) but they might have a very good relationship and notify them that you are actively looking for other job opportunities with other companies.

Comment: Luckily we do not use recruitment agencies where I work but thank you that was very informative.